# Incrementing a variable in a non-linear

Tags: math

I would like to be able to increase / decrease a variable in a non-linear, for example based on a curved line such as:
[image]
then in the linear case if the time (T) is 0, the variable (v) will be 0, and then T = 5 v = 0.5, T = 10 v = 1 while in the case of a curved line will have T = 0 v = 0, T = 5 v = 0.8, T = 10 v = 1.
No matter the programming language, I want to understand the theory to do a thing. I do not want a simple exponential or logarithmic function, I wish I could do this thing also with custom curves. thank you.

Comment: There are many "curved" functions that match your description. Are you interested in any particular function?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at "calculus" and "finite differences".

What you're after is the derivative of a general function or a finite difference approximation.

If your variable `y = f(x)`, then the first derivative of the function w.r.t. x can be thought of as the slope of the function at that point:

```
dy/dx = f'(x)
```

You can use this to approximate the increment in y for a given increment in x:

```
dy = f'(x)*dx
```

Your example y = ln(x) would look like:

```
f'(ln(x)) = 1/x
```

Rearranging:

```
dy = dx/x
```

If you know the value of your function at a point x0

```
y0 = f(x0)
```

and you want the value at another point x1

```
x1 = x0 + dx
```

You can approximate the value at a point x1 = x0 + dx by:

```
y1 = y0 + f'(x)*dx
```

Bonus points: do you evauate the derivative at x0 (explicit), x1 (implicit), or an intermediate point?